# Netbeans 11 gradle project output bat in distributions folder "The input line is too long"

Tags: java, gradle, netbeans, netbeans-11

I have a Java gradle project that I made with Netbeans 11.
I am using Windows 10 Pro.
In the build\distributions folder I have a bat file and if I try running it I get a "The input line is too long" error.
There is no jar file in the folder. There is just a file with no extension.
I think it has to do with the classpath being too long, but I have no idea how to make it shorter.
I can run it from netbeans just fine.
Also the output distribution size is almost 1GB in size.
Is there anyway I can make it smaller or at least make the error go away?
The optimal thing would be to make an exe out of the whole thing if that was possible, but even a running jar or bat would be ok.

Comment: Can you move the folder closer to the root?  Like “C:\here”?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen 
  F:\txtcstr\bin>txtcstr_pa01d.bat  The input line is too long.  
The syntax of the command is incorrect.   - shorter than that?

Comment: Then something else is wrong.  Try putting an "echo on" in top of the bat file.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen that changes nothing :( I added this "@echo on". Hope it is ok.

Comment: Look inside the file and find the line giving the problem.  Then look at it to see if you can understand why it became too long.   If you can't then strongly consider providing much more information.  Like sharing the project on github, and put a bounty on the questin.